# brightness not working ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: brightness

I've a Sumsung series 5 laptop with 4GB ram dual booted with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. My brightness does not work although the "function key+brightness button" shows the indication that it is being changed but brightness just does not really change. It works fine on Windows 10.

I tried `sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`

```
    Section "Device"
            Identifier  "card0"
            Driver      "intel"
            Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
            BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
    EndSection
```

Also,

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" to 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video.use_native_backlight=1"
```

Still the problem is there

please help

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I found a workaround by creating aliases to change the brightness value manually.

The file that contains the brightness value is:

```
/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

or something similar depending on your machine.

You can use an alias like that to add 100 to the brightness value:

```
bup='pres="$(cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness)" && pres=$(($pres+100)) && echo $pres | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness'
```

You can set up similar aliases to set it to lower the brightness or set it to specific values

**Setting permanent alias**

if you want your aliases to be available even after you reboot your machine, you should append the alias definition to the file:

```
~/.bashrc
```

Comment: How do you do it from keyboard keys?